# Ruby on Rails - Converting Hash of Datetimes to Dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, datetime

I am creating a calendar view based on this [Railscast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised). In the tutorial, the :published_on field is a date field. My question is, if :published_on were a datetime field instead of a date field, how would I adjust the code below to make it work?

**Migration**

```
t.date :published_on
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  @articles_by_date = @articles.group_by(&:published_on)
  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
end
```

**View:**

```
<div id="articles">
  <h2 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", date: @date.prev_month %>
    <%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", date: @date.next_month %>
  </h2>
  <%= calendar @date do |date| %>
    <%= date.day %>
    <% if @articles_by_date[date] %>
       <ul>
        <% @articles_by_date[date].each do |article| %>
          <li><%= link_to article.name, article %></li>
         <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't just `@date = params[:date] ? DateTime.parse(params[:date]) : DateTime.today` work?

Comment: Why doesn't it work without adjustments?

Comment: @grilix - that gives a `undefined method `today' for DateTime:Class` error. @Christoph - There is no error without adjustments, but it doesn't display any data in the calendar.  However, if I change it to a date field, it correctly displays the data.

Comment: Oops.. you are right, what about `DateTime.now`?

Comment: `DateTime.now` doesn't return an error, but it doesn't output anything on the calendar.

Comment: If you have a datetime field, don't you just call .date at the end to get the "date" part? eg  `@article.published_on.date`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

we need to group the articles only by date not datetime:

```
 @articles_by_date = Article.all.group_by {|i| i.created_at.to_date}
```

Delete the @articles line, it doesn't look like it does anything.

That should be all.

For a rails 3.x + approach use ActiveRecord [group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) function, it will perform the grouping using the DB, rather than instantiating all records then grouping.

```
@articles_by_date = Article.group("date(created_at)")
```