# Events don't displayed in calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, datetime, calendar

I've followed [Railscast #213](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised?view=asciicast) to create Calendar, which shows `current_user.events`. But my calendar doesn't display them.

I think, that the problem is because I'm using `datetime` instead of `date` as Ryan used in his cast. But I can't understand how to parse only date from my `datetime`.

I've tried to change `@date` variable to

```
@date = params[:datetime] ? DateTime.parse(params[:datetime]).to_date : Date.today
```

instead of

```
@date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
```

which is used in cast, but it didn't help.

So, my `events_controller#index` is:

```
def index
  @events = current_user.events.all
  @events_by_date = @events.group_by(&:start_date)
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  @date = params[:datetime] ? DateTime.parse(params[:datetime]).to_date : Date.today
end
```

Calendar Helper and `events#index` I've left without changes.

`calendar_helper.rb`

```
module CalendarHelper
  def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
  end

  class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    HEADER = %w[Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday]
    START_DAY = :monday

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def table
      content_tag :table, class: 'calendar' do
        header + week_rows
      end
    end

    def header
      content_tag :tr do
        HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
      end
    end

    def week_rows
      weeks.map do |week|
        content_tag :tr do
          week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
        end
      end.join.html_safe
    end

    def day_cell(day)
      content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
    end

    def day_classes(day)
      classes = []
      classes << 'today' if day == Date.today
      classes << 'notmonth' if day.month != date.month
      classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(' ')
    end

    def weeks
      first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
      last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
      (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
    end
  end
end
```

`index.html.erb`

```
<div id="events">
  <h2 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", date: @date.prev_month %>
    <%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", date: @date.next_month %>
  </h2>
  <%= calendar @date do |date| %>
      <%= date.day %>
      <% if @events_by_date[date] %>
          <ul>
            <% @events_by_date[date].each do |event| %>
                <li><%= link_to event.name, event %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In the block passed to `<%= calendar @date do |date| %>`, can you debug the values of `date.to_s` and `@events_by_date`? I have a feeling the keys of the `@events_by_date` hash does not equal the string value of `date`.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Keys of `@events_by_date` is formatted like `Mon, 10 Jun 2013 00:00:00 UTC +00:00` and `date.to_s` is `2013-06-10`. But how to change the format of keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973867/1419884)

The solution is to group events only by `date`, not `datetime`.

`@events_by_date = @events.group_by { |i| i.start_date.to_date }`

Joe Frambach had a right idea.